# SQL STATEMENT JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a table like with a column below (which has null and a link for object when clicked it takes details of that object like Name,EmailAddress....)

```
ID   COUNTRY 
1     null 
2     null 
3     null 
4     2zlad9.6f
```

I need to write a join query on the same table to get the "object.Name" in place of the "object" value of the column and the null value should remain same.

When used with JOIN on the same table it just gives the columns having the object where the columns having null are ignored.

I need all values of the Column like below

```
ID   COUNTRY 
1     null 
2     null 
3     null 
4     US
```

I have used the query like

```
Select p.ID, p.Country.Name 
from table1 p
JOIN table1 p2 ON p.ID=p2.ID
```

which just gives me

```
ID  Country
4    US
```

Comment: Please take the time to read your own question before posting.  The question is unclear.

Comment: Sample data, expected results using sample data and what you've tried so far are all good places to start.

Answer (score 1):

[`Null`](http://%20(though%20note%20that%20SQL%20Server%20and%20Oracle%20treat%20this%20value%20slight%20differently) represents nothing. It is not a value, per say, as much as it is a placemark for the lack of a value. If you are joining on a column that contains a `NULL` value then that means there is nothing to return from one of your data sets and you should see no values.

If you want to see an entire set plus the missing values from a second set look into [Outer Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) such as:

```
Select t1.id, t1.value
From table1 t1
Left Join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

**--- EDIT -----**

It's important to understand what you are asking when you do a join. When you say Select From Table1 Join Table2 on .... what you are saying is I have a series of values in table1 and I want to pull back all matches from Table2.

Make sure you are familiar with the Set Theory concepts of [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), [Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) and [Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)). Also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg) is a visual chart of the concepts of joins. Everything marked in red refers to the data you are pulling back.